# Is it a good idea to carry printouts of scanned documents in lieu of original documents to an interview for a B2 visa for USA?

Tags: visas, usa, paperwork

I am staying in USA on a H1B visa. I am planning to sponsor a B2 visa in USA for my parents who are living in India. I am on the way to prepare all sponsor documents. I am aware that for  the B2 visa interview, my parents have to carry sponsor documents along with other documents. After completing of the documents, I would like to scan all those documents and send those scanned copies to my parents through e-mail so that they can carry the printouts of sponsor documents to the B2 visa interview.

Is it good idea, or do we have to carry original documents for the B2 visa interview?

Answer (score 5):

They will have to present the **original documents**, from [immihelp.com](http://www.immihelp.com/visitor-visa/visitor-documents.html):

> **Sponsorship Documents** 
>   Applicants who do not have sufficient funds of their own to support themselves during their proposed stay in the United States must present credible evidence to show that they will be supported there by some interested person; such evidence should reflect the ties between applicant and sponsor which form the basis for the latter's assurances of extending support. 
>    **You should present [all original documents](/visitor-visa/sponsor-documents.html) sent to you by your sponsor in the USA**.