# Is it OK if I take a printout of soft copy for Employment letter and bank letter?

Tags: usa, paperwork, b1-b2-visas

I have learned from the below post that B2 VISA applicants carry originals of  I-134, letter to Consulate, Invitation letter, Employment letter and Bank statement to their visa interview.

[Is it a good idea to carry printouts of scanned documents in lieu of original documents to an interview for a B2 visa for USA?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26954/is-it-a-good-idea-to-carry-printouts-of-scanned-documents-in-lieu-of-original-do)

I have applied B2 visa for my parents. And their interview is scheduled in 2 weeks from now. I have sent I-134, Letter to Consulate and invitation letter in post to my parents. I have put request for Employment letter and Bank letter. Due to unexpected delays they are not yet get in my hand. It seems to be they are going to take some more time to get in hand as both bank and my employer has to post to my current address. And then I have post those to my parents in india.

I am thinking worst case. There are good number of chances that the document will not reach before their interview date. Hence my question is

Is it OK to attend B2 visa interview with print outs of soft copy of employment letter and bank letter?

Comment: If the papers didn't arrive before time, then you have no choice but to let them attend, it will be better than not attending at all. Out of personal experience, when you do not bring some papers, they will set a new appointment, not refuse the whole thing, so tell your parents to explain the reason behind this.

Comment: Where are your parents applying from?

Comment: @AdityaSomani, From India

Answer (score 1):

B2 visa is by definition a document-less visa. None of the documents you mentioned are mandated. It is advisable to carry those because it keeps the applicant prepared and confident to come up with proofs should something come up.

Having said that, it is perfectly okay to let them carry the printouts, and not worry them with not having the originals.

I processed B2 visa for my parents last month and the only document I sent physically was the I-134. I sent soft copies for all the others and guess what, they were not asked to produce a single document before being granted the visas.